# Authentication pop-up issue with Selenium

Tags: selenium, java

[image]

How to enter credentials using Selenium (Java)? I am not able to enter credentials in the Pop-up window, which is shown above.
Please help me in this. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is common known problem. Solution that I've implement in my automation test is simple:
to open page without basic http authorization You must use url with template: login:password@site. For example:

page: xyz.com
login: admin
password: adminpassword

url: `admin:adminpassword@xyz.com`

Comment: yes, i have already tried this, but it not works for me

Comment: And also it throws me "The address wasn't understood" exception

Comment: this format is not accepted in IE. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox has protection against phishing, so with  http://username:password@serveraddress:portnumber/webname/ the very first login should be made manually. If someone knows how to disable it, please make the answer bellow. Additionally, the dialog is appearing before selenium get's the control over the window and therefore it is not possible to reach it as an popup.